# App in App Store and Apple Watch app installation fails for some users — can I make installation more reliable somehow?

Tags: ios, installation, apple-watch, watchos-2, watchos

I have an app in the [App Store with an Apple Watch app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pee-see-drink-more-water/id1090749982?mt=8). For most users, installation works fine.

Some users have had a problem where the Apple Watch app installation fails at what appears to be 75% (based on the pie graph status indicator over the app icon on the Apple Watch). Out of these users, many of them have eventually been able to get it to install after rebooting both the Apple Watch and paired iPhone a few times or updating the software on both.

At least one person has not been able to resolve the installation issue. He has gone to great lengths troubleshooting, including erasing and restoring his iPhone Apple Watch multiple times. All the other Apple Watch apps that are part of iPhone apps on his phone get automatically installed, except for mine, which fails.

Is there anything I might be able to do as a developer to troubleshoot the failing installation further, and possibly change about my app to make the installation process more reliable?

I've talked to a number of other developers about this, and they all seem to think it must be a bug in iOS or watchOS that I don't have any control over as a developer, but I really want to help this guy out who is having trouble installing my app so I thought I'd post here to try to get more feedback on what's happening.

I always try to post at least some code or log output in my questions, but unfortunately in this case don't really have any relevant code or logs related to this issue since it's all during the installation process.

Comment: Have you asked the user to install Xcode (or a third-party tool) to get the install failure reason from the device's console log?

Comment: @PetahChristian I didn't even know that was an option. Thanks, I'll try that!

Answer (score 0):

After PetahChristian's comment on my question, I asked the person with the installation issue to download XCode and check the device's console log. Here is the relevant line from the console output:

```
Jun 16 10:44:40 WeeFee appconduitd[1843] <Error>: 0x16e12f000 -[ACXServerInstallOperation receivedDictionaryOrData:]: 524: Got error 17 in install done from remote side (MI error DeviceOSVersionTooLow ; Extended 0x0 ; Desc The system version is lower than the minimum OS version specified for bundle at /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.eMUVkq/extracted/Payload/Pee and See Watch.app. Have 2.1; need 2.2)
```

Even though I had asked this person if he had iOS and watchOS up to date, and he told me he did, it turns out he didn't. And, Apple seems to just let the installation fail without showing the user an error message about software updates being required to run the app. Once he actually did update watchOS, everything worked fine with the installation.